# How to share business logic between DTO & domain model?

Tags: domain-driven-design, dto, domain-model

I'm trying to refactor a codebase that was passing domain models to the views, to use DTOs instead.

Overall everything looks cleaner now, except one point: I have some business logic that belongs to the domain but needs to be executed in the view as well.

Example: I have an `Activity` class, that has a method to check whether a given `User` can edit it:

```php
class Activity {
    public function isEditableBy(User $user): bool {
        ...
    }
}
```

- The domain service layer uses this method to ensure that the Activity can be edited, and throw an exception if not.
- The view uses this method to display an Edit button if the Activity is editable by the user.

Question: **How to avoid duplicating this logic in the DTO and the model?**

Comment: Is it a single tear application?

Comment: @plalx Single tier for now, yes. But best practices for future expansion welcome, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thing you should not put logic in the DTO at all due to its definition "Data Transfer Object". So, "data" not "logic". Instead you can calculate result of the isEditableBy() method in your application service layer, put this result into a DTO and use the DTO in the view layer.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!